# ViewHolder Pattern - ListView - Item's background color doesn't get set properly

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with custom adapter. The only item in the listview is a TextView(for now). When I click on the TextView, the background colour should change to blue and when I click it again, the background colour should change to a default colour(light grey). I am trying to implement this using ViewHolder Pattern.

The problem now is, when I click on first item in the list, some random item's background color changes to blue.

CustomAdapter class:

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ViewHolder holder;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dummyText.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.item_mtf_results, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewResults = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview_item_mtf_results);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtViewResults.setText(dummyText[position]);

        holder.txtViewResults.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "in onClick Method");
                Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Is checked ? = " + holder.isChecked);

                String result = holder.txtViewResults.getText().toString();
                listener.onResultClick(result);

                if (holder.isChecked) {

                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "isChecked = true");

                    holder.txtViewResults.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.light_grey));
                    holder.txtViewResults.setTextColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.black));
                    holder.isChecked = false;

                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                            "Holder is set to false..  checked ? = "
                                    + holder.isChecked);

                } else {

                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "isChecked = false");

                    holder.txtViewResults.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.blue));
                    holder.txtViewResults.setTextColor(getResources()
                            .getColor(R.color.white));
                    holder.isChecked = true;

                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG,
                            "Holder is set to true..  checked ? = "
                                    + holder.isChecked);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ViewHolder Class:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewResults;
    boolean isChecked = false;
}
```

Let me know if you need any other code...

Comment: Why do you need is checked in holder? See if you can set the boolean as a Tag to the textview instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the clickListenr for the text view inside the `converview==null` block. Listners are set every time you scroll the listview.